# Show that every continuous map $f:M\longrightarrow M$ which is homotopic to the identity has a fixed point

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a 4-dimensional closed simply connected manifold.  Show that every continuous map $f:M\longrightarrow M$ which is homotopic to the identity has a fixed point.

We have the Lefschetz Fixed Point Theorem that says: If $X$ is a finite simplicial complex, or more generally a retract of a finite simplicial complex, and $f: X\rightarrow X$ is a map with $\tau (f) \neq 0$, then $f$ has a fixed point.

Hatcher says (p.179) that since $f$ is homotopic to the identity, we have $\tau (f) = \chi (X)$.  (The Lefschetz number of $f$ equals the Euler characteristic of $M$.)

I also found in a paper that: "When $X$ is simply connected manifold, the Lefschetz number provides a complete invariant in that the map $f$ is deformable to a fixed point free map if and only if $\tau (f) = 0$."

(So, we've used simply connectedness of $M$ and that $f$ is homotopic to the identity.  All that's left to use from our assumptions is the fact that $M$ is a 4-dimensional closed manifold. )

So, if I can say that $\chi (M)\neq 0$, then I'm done.

However, I can't seem to find what the Euler characteristic of $M$ is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't actually used simply connectedness.  If $\chi(M)\neq 0$, then you're already done, without using the result you quoted.  All that result would give you that you couldn't do already is a sort of converse (if $\tau(f)=0$, then $f$ is homotopic to a map with no fixed points).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $\chi(M) = h_0 - h_1 + h_2 - h_3 + h_4$, where $h_i$ is the rank (dimension) of $H_i(M;\mathbb{F})$.  Since $M$ is simply connected, $h_1 = 0$.  Also, using Poincar\'{e} duality and the universal coefficient theorem, $h_3 = 0$ too.  So assuming $M$ is nonempty, we have $\chi(M) > 0$.

Comment: What about $h_0,h_2,h_4$?

Comment: +1, very nice. @Michael: since $M$ is nonempty, $h_{0}$ is nonzero (it counts the number of connected components of $M$.) Hence, $\chi(M) = h_{0} + h_{2} + h_{4} > h_{0} > 0$.

Comment: Okay, got it thanks!

Comment: For Poincare duality don't you need $M$ to be an n-dimensional oriented closed manifold? We don't have that $M$ is orientable.

Comment: @Michael You can either use $\Bbb Z/2$ coefficients (whose alternating sum also gives the Euler characteristic) or note that simply connected manifolds are orientable.

Comment: Did you use Poincare Duality to find that $H^1(M)\cong H_3(M)$?  And then how did you use the Universal Coefficient theorem to find that $h_3 = 0$?

Comment: Yes for Poincare duality, and then UCT says $H^i(M; \mathbb{F}) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_i(M; \mathbb{F}), \mathbb{F})$ is an isomorphism, so the ranks of $H^i(M; \mathbb{F})$ and $H_i(M; \mathbb{F})$ are equal.